# css "opacity" property not supporting

Tags: css, asp.net

```
<style>
.imgopacity{
    opacity:0.2px;
}
</style>
```

In the above CSS code, the opacity property is not supported, how to obtaining the opacity property if anyhow i want to have one.

Comment: where are you applying that.

Comment: Which browser are you using? According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) it is supported on all browsers though. Also, it might be easier for other to spot the problem if you could post a snippet of code with html and css. You could add that to the question using the `<>` button in the edit menu.

Comment: it works on few things being displayed on screen.

Answer (score 1):

`Opacity` property is not measured in pixels . its a ratio from 0 to 1 to indicate the transparency of an element so your code should be :

```
<style>
  .imgopacity
  {
    opacity:0.2;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.imgopacity { 
    /* IE 8 */ 
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";      

    /* IE 5-7 */ 
    filter: alpha(opacity=20); 

    /* Old Mozilla */ 
    -moz-opacity: 0.2; 

    /* Safari 1.x */ 
    -khtml-opacity: 0.2; 

    /* Compliant browsers */ 
    opacity: 0.2; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.imgopacity {
    opacity:0.2;
}
```

Simply remove that **px** from your CSS code. The **opacity** property does not take value in pixels. It can take a value **from 0.0 to 1.0**. The lower the value, the more transparent the image will be. For browsers like IE8 and earlier use `filter:alpha(opacity=x)`, where **x** is a value **from 0 to 100**.